# java xml parsing: instant updating of file

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have the following piece of xml code:

```
<Sequence>
<PreCommand>
 <Copy>
   <Source>pahtToSourceFile</Source>
   <Dest>pathToDest</Dest>
 </Copy>
```

What I would like to do is change the source element. Is there a way in Java of looping through an xml and updating it as it finds a source tag? I am very new to xml parsing in java.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Many tutorials on XML parsing online. For your use case I would recommend a SAX parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DOM parser; which is handy for editing the XML.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: "_SAX Parser is only to read XML_" who says that??

Comment: Found this 10 seconds before @Kanagavelu Sugumar
 posted this answer. Good because I was using DOMparser already.

Answer (score 0):

By using `DomParser` we create or edit XML.

[Refference Link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find about [sax-parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)

`DomParser` already on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857926/xml-parsing-using-dom-in-java)